# Double Series Identity

Tags: summation

Show that $$\sum_{k=2}^n (-1)^k \sum_{j=1}^{k-1} a_ja_{k-j} = \Bigl(\sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^ka_k\Bigr)^2 - \sum_{k=n+1}^{2n} (-1)^k \sum_{j=k-n}^n a_ja_{k-j}$$ Source: [Determine whether $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}\frac{(-1)^k}{[j(k-j)]^p}$ converges](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3607284/determine-whether-sum-k-1-infty-sum-j-1k-1-frac-1kjk-jp-c).

I'm not quire sure how to prove this. Does anybody have an idea or suggestion? Thanks.

Comment: Start by writing out the grid $$ \begin{matrix} a_1 a_1 & a_1 a_2 & a_1 a_3 & \cdots \\ a_2 a_1 & a_2 a_2 \\ \vdots && \ddots  \end{matrix} $$ and start crossing out terms that are being summed in each of the levels of the summations. The pattern is not too hard to see after you do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I'm "the author", I think I have to explain it myself. Start with $$\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}b_k\right)^2=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}b_i b_j=\sum_{\substack{1\leqslant i,j\leqslant n\\i+j\leqslant n}}b_i b_j+\sum_{\substack{1\leqslant i,j\leqslant n\\i+j>n}}b_i b_j.$$ In the first sum on the RHS, we collect the terms with fixed value of $k:=i+j$ (which runs from $1+1=2$ to $n$); the possible values of $j$ are from $1$ to $k-1$, and for a fixed value of $j$, the (single possible) value of $i$ is then equal to $k-j$. Thus, the first sum is equal to $\sum_{k=2}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}b_j b_{k-j}$.

Similarly, if we fix $k=i+j$ in the second sum (the possible values of $k$ run from $n+1$ to $2n$), then the smallest possible value of $j$ is $k-n$ (and the greatest one is $n$ of course), and the single possible value of $i$ (for a fixed $j$) is then again $k-j$.

This explains $$\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}b_k\right)^2=\sum_{k=2}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}b_j b_{k-j}+\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}\sum_{j=k-n}^{n}b_j b_{k-j}.$$ Now put $b_k=(-1)^k a_k$.